# How can I identify the source of calls to Instance Metadata Service Version 1 (IMDSv1)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to transition to using the Instance Metadata Service Version 2 (IMDSv2).  I've been following the steps in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-service.html#instance-metadata-transition-to-version-2, which mentions using a CloudWatch metric to see if anything is still calling IMDSv1:

> **CloudWatch**: IMDSv2 uses token-backed sessions, while IMDSv1 does not.
> The `MetadataNoToken` CloudWatch metric tracks the number of calls to
> the instance metadata service that are using IMDSv1. By tracking this
> metric to zero, you can determine if and when all of your software has
> been upgraded to use IMDSv2.

I don't want to guess which instances may still be making calls to IMDSv1, and I don't necessarily want to disable IMDSv1 one-by-one on instances until I find one that breaks.  I want to know where the calls are coming from first. I've heard some CLI actions will call it, but that is a black box to me.  I see the MetadataNoToken metric in CloudWatch, but how can I tell which instances are still making the calls to IMDSv1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized in CloudWatch I could find the `MetadataNoToken` metric under "Per-Instance Metrics," which at least will show the instance ID for each instance.  I was just looking under "Across All Instances" before.  Seems obvious now.

I am still not able to see what specific process/action on the instance is calling IMDSv1, but at least I can identify which instances are making calls:
[image]

Also useful: https://blog.appsecco.com/getting-started-with-version-2-of-aws-ec2-instance-metadata-service-imdsv2-2ad03a1f3650

---

**Update June 1 2023**: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76805699/230055) from xuc mentions a new [IMDS Packet Analyzer tool](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/06/imds-packet-analyzer-simplifies-migration-imdsv2/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20now%20use%20the,or%20manage%20the%20running%20instance) that is available to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

A new [tool](https://github.com/aws/aws-imds-packet-analyzer) (IMDS Packet Analyzer) is available from AWS for identifying IMDSv1 calls.

[https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/06/imds-packet-analyzer-simplifies-migration-imdsv2/#:~:text=You%20can%20now%20use%20the,or%20manage%20the%20running%20instance](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/06/imds-packet-analyzer-simplifies-migration-imdsv2/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20now%20use%20the,or%20manage%20the%20running%20instance).